# cakephp 3.0 + group by + count +paginate

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have one table user and another table games.

Now user will create games. And now I want list of user with his count of games he created.

Below query will output (IN PHPMYADMIN) exactly what I want.
But I don't have idea how to fire such query in cakephp 3.0:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,(select count(id) from games where games.created_by=users.id) FROm users group by `users`.`id`
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation around retrieving data - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller :

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all', [
        'fields' => [
            'id' => 'Users.id',
            'firstname' => 'firstname',
            'lastname' => 'lastname',
            'count_games' => 'COUNT(games.id)'
        ],
        'join' => [
            'table' => 'games', 
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'games.created_by = Users.id'
        ],
        'group' => ['Users.id'],
]);
$this->set('users', $users);
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```

Comment: HI this works but pagination sort link is not working on two field.

Comment: How to use this with **$this->paginate**

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code for sort

```
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('count_games_created','Number of games created') ?></th>
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('count_games_joined','Number of games attended') ?></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I come with a **pretty good** solution : [CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) !

Everytime you add a new `game` to your `user`, the number of games `game_count` in user table is updated.
It works and it's a **faster** solution.